# How to Insert string in another string in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

the following code shows invalid qualifier when executed

```
Dim strs As String
Dim insStr As String
Dim strRes As String

strs = "This is VB.NET Test"
insStr = "Insert"
strRes = strs.Insert(insStr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to say where in the string it should be inserted.

```
strRes = strs.Insert(strs.Length \ 2, insStr)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the signature of [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx), you can see it takes *two* parameters. You have only supplied one. You need to specify what place to insert the second string into:

```
Dim strs As String
Dim insStr As String
Dim strRes As String
Dim index As Integer = 0

strs = "This is VB.NET Test"
insStr = "Insert"
strRes = strs.Insert(index, insStr) 
'strRes = "InsertThis is VB.NET Test"
```